# Parse error with Happy and attributed grammar

Tags: parsing, haskell, grammar, happy

I'm a newbie of Haskell and Happy and I'm trying to make a parser with an attributed grammar in Haskell with Happy. I've made a little grammar just for variable declarations, given to BNFC and everything since here works fine. Then I start to add the attributes in the parser and at this point I found my first problem: when I add `%attributetype {MyAttribute a}`

`happy -gca Pargrammar.y` works fine, but immediately after I add `%attribute parseTree {a}`

happy gives me this parse error

> happy: Parse error

So I keep just `%attributetype {MyAttribute a}` and try to modify the basic type changing first

```
String  :: { String }  : L_quoted {  $1 }
```

with this line here

```
String  : L_quoted { $$= $1 }
```

but then my second problem arises: when I launch the Makefile I got this error here

> Pargrammar.hs:344:19: error:
>       Variable not in scope: ($$=) :: t1 -> String -> t
>
> Pargrammar.hs:1066:19: error:
>
> ```
> • Couldn't match type ‘t1 -> t’ with ‘[Char]’
>   Expected type: HappyAbsSyn String
>     Actual type: HappyAbsSyn (t1 -> t)
> • In the first argument of ‘fn’, namely ‘v1’
>   In the expression: fn v1
>   In an equation for ‘r’: r = fn v1
> • Relevant bindings include
>     r :: HappyAbsSyn (t1 -> t) (bound at Pargrammar.hs:1066:12)
>     stk' :: HappyStk (HappyAbsSyn (t1 -> t))
>       (bound at Pargrammar.hs:1065:81)
>     v1 :: HappyAbsSyn (t1 -> t) (bound at Pargrammar.hs:1065:69)
>     fn :: HappyAbsSyn String -> HappyAbsSyn (t1 -> t)
>       (bound at Pargrammar.hs:1065:22)
>     happySpecReduce_1 :: Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#
>                          -> (HappyAbsSyn String -> HappyAbsSyn (t1 -> t))
>                          -> Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#
>                          -> Token
>                          -> Happy_GHC_Exts.Int#
>                          -> Happy_IntList
>                          -> HappyStk (HappyAbsSyn (t1 -> t))
>                          -> [Token]
>                          -> Err (HappyAbsSyn (t1 -> t))
>       (bound at Pargrammar.hs:1063:1)
> ```

and indeed at line 344 of the Pargrammar.hs I got this

```
happyIn8
        ($$= happy_var_1
    )
```

but that `$$=` should not be there.

My Makefile just do this

```
all:
    happy -gca Pargrammar.y
    alex -g Lexgrammar.x
    ghc --make Testgrammar.hs -o Testgrammar

clean:
    -rm -f *.log *.aux *.hi *.o *.dvi
    -rm -f Docgrammar.ps

distclean: clean
    -rm -f Docgrammar.* Lexgrammar.* Pargrammar.* Layoutgrammar.* Skelgrammar.* Printgrammar.* Testgrammar.* Absgrammar.* Testgrammar ErrM.* SharedString.* ComposOp.* grammar.dtd XMLgrammar.* Makefile*
```

I really don't know how to solve this. If any of you can suggest me some ideas I would be grateful.

Comment: The symbol `$$=` is not the same thing as the two consecutive symbols `$$ =`. As you can see, happy parses `$$=` as just a regular Haskell operator (because it is) and so `$$= $1` is parsed as an operator section. As the docs say, if you have only `attributetype` and no `attribute`, then the former is simply ignored. When you add an `attribute`, the syntax of happy changes, because an attribute grammar and a 'regular' grammar do not use precisely the same syntax. (All this information comes from about 90 seconds of reading the happy docs)